# How to customise html code to allow quick modification of content

Tags: html, css

I have created a site where I want to constantly modify data. This means adding more text, adding files and etc. I was wondering how I could do that. I could possible do it using a cms but I do not understand how to integrate it with my site. This is an example of my site-page.

I would constantly need to add a new date with new files of the same style.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs9tj.png

Comment: Hi, this is a bit vague. Where will the new data be coming from, and what mechanism do you have for storing all the data that has been input so far? e.g. have you got a server with a database?

Answer (score 0):

If your constantly adding new content, I would suggest trying to use Javascript ES6 or possibly React.

Using Javascript DOM, would be the best way. Definitely consider using document.getElementById().innerHTML